# In python how to access and update the JSON's specific property with path/map is available as string

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, eval, python-3.7

I have complex JSON object "my_json_obj" and want to access particular property but I have path/map to the property as string
e.g.

```
map = "['newobj'][0]['root_str'][1]['home_str'][1]"
```

and I want to use the above map/path as

```
my_json_obj['root1'][0]['check1'][1]['home_str'][1]
```

But As "map" is a string so I am not really able to do this.

I tried doing:

```
eval(f"{my_json_obj}{map}")
```

It gives back the expected instance/obj/property but as separate copy, I want to update the actual my_json_obj and not the copy returned from eval.

**Note:
This map string is dynamically generated so can not use it hardcoded.**

Comment: Why do you think this returns a copy? It shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the value, try using:

```
exec(f"my_json_obj{map} = value")
```

for example:

```
exec(f"my_json_obj{map} = 2 * 3")
```

note that `2 * 3` isn't surounded by braces.